# Java: Making a checkerboard (8x8)

Tags: java

I'm getting the checkerboard pattern in my first column; however, i Cannot get it to keep going through the whole board. This is just to brush up on my skills as a programmer. Let me know what I can improve on!
(The code in question)

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    //Creates pane
    AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    int columns = 8, row = 8, horizontal = 125, vertical = 125;
    Rectangle rectangle = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < row; j++){
            //creates the rectangles, and outlines them
            rectangle = new Rectangle(horizontal*j, vertical*i, horizontal, vertical);
            rectangle.setStroke(Color.WHITE);

                    if ( j+i % 2 == 0 ) {
                        rectangle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                    } else {
                        rectangle.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                    }//end else

            //put rectangles into the pane
            pane.getChildren().add(rectangle);
        }//end for-loop j
    }//end for-loop i

    //create a scene and place it in the stage
    scene.setRoot(pane);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Checkerboard");
    primaryStage.show();
}//end primaryStage
```

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: Download and use an IDE like Eclipse.  You can add `System.out.println ("some msg")+` before each of the `setFill` statements so that you can check that the correct code is being actioned

Comment: You need to learn how to do stuff like this yourself. Debugging your own programs is a skill you're supposed to have.

Comment: Why are code-dump answers, posted without explanation getting accepted while answers that actually explain the problem and its solution are not? Disheartening.

Comment: It's the classic, "here let me teach you to learn" vs "here let me teach you how to beg for others to do your complete work for you"

Comment: At least accept the better answer,  not the one that spoonfeeds you code,  but rather the one that offers an explanation.

Comment: It's not a problem, here you can get all need help for your growth

Comment: I spent a little bit time to give you a worked version of code and will be help you in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%` has higher precedence then `+` and was evaluated first. Use brackets to get the right calculation.

`if (((j + i) % 2) == 0 ) {`